# Shell script to unzip as a post build step on Jenkins too slow

Tags: shell, jenkins, unzip

I am executing the unzip command as a shell script in the post build step on Jenkins. The files will be in unzipped on a remote location. The size of the zip archive is 37.5 MB. The command takes a long time though. 1 hour and it is still going. Is there a way to speed up the process?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I cannot place comments (yet).

You need to investigate where the data bottleneck is. Is it the connection to remote or the unzip process by itself.
I assume the remote connection is the problem. An initial unzip and (depending on your platform) an `rsync` to remote should be pretty fast and solve what you want.